# How to call a constructor with unique_ptr declaration and handle the program termination signal

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, unique-ptr

I have created a class with a constructor.

I am creating *n number* of objects in `main.cpp`. Now with each object creation, the constructor should be called automatically.

But since I am creating this object in `main.cpp`, I want to use signals to handle the "Ctrl+C" termination.

I have written the `main.cpp` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Session.hpp"

class Session {
public:
    Session(int _count):count(_count) {
        std::cout << "Create Session " << count << std::endl;
    }
    ~Session() {
        std::cout << "Destroy Session " << count << std::endl;
    }
    Print() {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
    }
private:
    const int count;
};

void signal_handler(int signal, unsigned int count, **WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE**) {
    for (unsigned int del_count = 0; del_count < count; del_count++) {
        **I WANT TO DELETE ALL THE FOO OBJECTS CREATED IN THE MAIN FUNCTION**
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned int num_of_sessions;
    cin >> num_of_sessions;

    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler, num_of_sessions, **WHAT MORE SHOULD I PASS HERE**);

    unique_ptr<Session> Foo[num_of_sessions];
    unsigned int count = 0; // initialize the counter for sessions

    while (count < num_of_sessions) {
        Foo[count] (new Session(count));
        count++;
    }
    while (true){
        for (count = 0; count < num_of_sessions; count++) {
            Foo[count]->PrintName();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error as

> error: no match for call to ‘(std::unique_ptr) (Session*)’
>      Foo[count] (new Session(count));

Any suggestion?

Comment: yes. Foo[count].reset( new Session(count) );

Comment: In your signal handler function you could set a flag that your infinite loop checks. If set then the loop breaks, the `main` function ends which will destruct all your objects in the `Foo` array, which will delete the pointers and destruct the `Session` objects.

Comment: As for your build error, which is very different from the signal-handler problem and should have been asked as a separate question, that's not how you construct *any* object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `you could set a flag that your infinite loop checks` Can you suggest any example which implements this?

Comment: `std::atomic<bool> end_infinite_loop = false; void signal_handler(int) { end_infinite_loop = true; } ... int main() { ... while (!end_infinite_loop) { ... } }`

Comment: So after the `while(!end_infinite_loop){...}` I will have to write the code for deleting the objects. Right?

Comment: Nope, you don't. The variable `Foo` goes out of scope, meaning all elements in the array will be destructed. The `std::unique_ptr<Session>` destructor will `delete` the `Session` object you have created. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It works now. Thanks for providing the understanding too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to delete unique_ptr, they will be destroyed when the variable goes out of scope; in this case it will be the end of the main function.

That's the point of unique_ptr, you don't have to take care of memory management.

If you simply want to set a signal and perform an action on an object allocated in the stack inside the main function you can just use a pointer like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<bool> end_condition;
class Session {
    public:
    Session(int _count):count(_count) {
        std::cout << "Create Session " << count << std::endl;
    }
    ~Session() {
        std::cout << "Destroy Session " << count << std::endl;
    }
    void printSessionCount() {
        std::cout << "Session count is " << count << std::endl;
    }
    private:
    const int count;
};
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Session>>* foo_p; // <= Probably not necessary but this is how you would access your variable defined in main in signal handler

void signal_handler(int signal) {
   // You don't have handle clean up of your vector.
   // foo_p->clear(); <= Unnecessary to delete every element of your vector here, since they will be automatically deleted at the end of main
    end_condition.store(false);
}

int main() {
    end_condition.store(true);
    unsigned int num_of_sessions;
    std::cin >> num_of_sessions;

    // register signal SIGINT and signal handler
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Session> > foo;
    foo_p = &foo; // Make your global pointer points to your pointer created in the main function. Accessing foo_p before the point will result in a segmentation fault since the pointer will be null
   // You may not need this at all depending on what you want to do during in the signal handler

    for(int i = 0; i < num_of_sessions; ++i) {
        // Populate your vector
        foo.emplace_back(new Session(i));
    }

    while (end_condition.load()){
        //Call a function for each vector
        for(int i =0; i < foo.size(); ++i) {
            foo.at(i)->printSessionCount();
        }
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    return 0;
}    // vector foo memory will be deleted here
```

Comment: Hey Clonk Thanks for the answer. I am not very good with the vector. Can you tell me how will I use each object in the vector to call a function the Session class? Please see the edit for reference

Comment: I edited the answer to call a function on the while loop. I also added a temporisation of your while loop to avoid looping too fast (also an example of using std::chrono and std::thread)

Comment: Do note that you should use `std::vector` instead of c-array, it is safer and you can change the size dynamically.